# $a)$Show that there is a nontrivial group homomorphism $ φ : G →S_{k}.$ and show that G has a nontrivial proper normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group of order n, H a subgroup of G of order m, $k =\frac{n}{m}$
and $S_{k}$ the symmetric group on    $ k$ symbols

$a)$Show that there is a nontrivial group homomorphism $ φ : G →S_{k}.$

$b)$ Assuming  $ \frac{k!}{2}< n$, show that G has a nontrivial proper normal
subgroup

My idea : i was thinking about  fisrt theorem of isomorphism

Pliz help me ,,as im very much confused....

Comment: Have you seen group actions?

Comment: That's your comment upon being asked a very specific question?

Comment: Because you seem to be completely unwilling to make an effort yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equivalence relation defined on $G$ by $x\simeq y$ iff $x=yh, h\in H$, the cardinal of the set $G/H$ of equivalence classes is $k$ and $G$ acts on $G/H$ by $g(xH)=(gx)H$ by an action defined by $f:G\rightarrow S_k$ This action is not trivial sincd $G$ acts transitively.

Suppose that $k!/2<n$, if $f$ is not surjective, the image of $f$ is a subgroup $L$ and $card(L)$ divides $k!$ this implies that $card(L)\leq k!/2$ and the kernel is not trivial.
If $f$ is surjective $f^{-1}(A_k)$ is a non trivial subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Given the complete lack of interaction from the OP (see their reply to my comment), I don't think answering this will actually help them.

Comment: As a teacher in particular for someone who is not in front of me, I won't comment on the interaction of OP to discourage him in his learning since  maybe  he is a beginner, and  what  appears trivial for me is not necessarily trivial for him.

Comment: thanks a lots @TsemoAristide

Comment: I asked whether he had seen a specific concept, and his reply was "pliz help me.....". That is the utmost lack of wanting to make the slightest effort.

Comment: @Michael Because I am not interested in providing complete solutions to what is potentially a homework problem of a student unwilling to learn.